# Only allow TabView page swipe gestures that start in rightmost 20% of screen

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, tabview

I'm using page style TabView to display some views (MyView). The views have components inside that can be dragged, and so the TabView is interfering with this.

I'd like it so that the tab view swiping only works / is recognised when the gesture begins in the rightmost 20% of the screen, so that the rest of the view can recognise the drag gestures of the MyView.

```swift
TabView {
    ForEach(0..<5) { _ in
        MyView()
    }
}
.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
.indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You would have to create your own

Comment: @loremipsum I don't suppose you have any tips on how to get started?

Comment: No, everything would have to be custom. Maybe a good start would be to look at packages on git and see how they implement their custom tab views, I’ve seen a ton from time to time.